# ASP.Net MVC 4 SimpleMembership UserID as Foreign Key

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, simplemembership

Dear SO members please help me to get unstuck in what I thought should be an easy task but I have been stuck in for 2 days. I have a couple of tables that need to have a FK to the UserId of the currently logged in user. Here is an example

UserProfile

```
    [Table("UserProfile")]
    public class UserProfile
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string ManagerName { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
   }
```

A customer entity

```
 public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string Names { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserProfile")]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
    }
```

The DB Context

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
    {
        public UsersContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    }
```

Customer Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        [InitializeSimpleMembership]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(Customer model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                model.UserProfile = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
                db.Customers.Add(model);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.UserProfiles, "UserId", "UserName", model.UserId);
            return View(model);
        }
```

Also tried

```
 [HttpPost]
    [InitializeSimpleMembership]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Customer model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.UserId = WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
            db.Customers.Add(model);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.UserProfiles, "UserId", "UserName", model.UserId);
        return View(model);
    }
```

In each case I get the error message

```
"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Customers_dbo.UserProfile_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "ValueCardProject", table "dbo.UserProfile", column 'UserId'.
The statement has been terminated."
```

All I want to do is to be able to create tables with a FK to the UserID of the logged in user. For the interest of full disclosure, Customers should not be created directly as users, in my use case the current logged in users is a Retailer, so what I am trying to accomplish is to create a customer record with the FK to RetailerId (which is the UserId in the UserProfile).

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Because you are trying to add the same user. `GetUserId` will return the information for a user that already exists, and then you are using that `Id` to create a new user with the same `Id`

Comment: Is a user currently logged into the system? What value does WebSecurity.CurrentUserId return? Does it match an entry in the UserProfile table?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your foreign key attribute on UserId is in the wrong place.

you should be doing this instead:

```
public int UserId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("UserId")]
public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
```